# My TestNG BeforeMethod and AfterMethod annotations are not executing before or after the @Test annotated method

Tags: testng

Folksm I'm using TestNG 7.5 and Selenium 4.2.2, with IntelliJ and Java 11.

I've got all my bits imported and my tests will run individually, but I'm trying to get my setup and cleanup methods to work with the before and after annotations. Here's a code sample:

```
   public static class RunTest {
      WebDriver driver;
      WaitUtils waitUtils;
      Actions actions;
      StateUtils stateUtils;

      public RunTest(WebDriver givenDriver){
         this.driver = givenDriver;
         this.actions = new Actions(givenDriver);
         this.waitUtils = new WaitUtils(givenDriver);
         this.stateUtils = new StateUtils(givenDriver);
      }

      @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
      public void login(){
         System.out.println("test_++++++++++++");
         boolean firstLoginPageFound = true;

         driver.navigate().to("http://www.amazon.ca");
         InteractionUtils interactionUtils = new InteractionUtils(driver);
         try{
            interactionUtils.clickOnElementByXpath("//div[@class='nav-bb-right']/a[text()='Your Account']");
         } catch  (NoSuchElementException e){
            firstLoginPageFound = false;
         }

         interactionUtils.clickOnElementByXpath("//span[@id='nav-link-accountList-nav-line-1']");

         byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("");

         waitUtils.waitForVisibilityOfLocator("//input[@id='ap_email']").sendKeys(new String(decodedBytes));

         interactionUtils.clickOnElementByXpath("//input[@id='continue']");

         decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("");
         waitUtils.waitForVisibilityOfLocator("//input[@id='ap_password']").sendKeys(new String(decodedBytes));

         interactionUtils.clickOnElementByXpath("//input[@id='signInSubmit']");
      }

      @Test
      public void checkLandingPage(){
         System.out.println("REST++++++++++++");
         Assert.assertTrue(stateUtils.verifyElementIsVisible("//div[@id='nav-xshop']//a[contains(@class, 'nav-a') and text()='Buy Again']"), "Buy again button is missing");
      }

      @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
      public void cleanUp(){
         System.out.println("BEST++++++++++++");
         driver.close();
      }
   }
```

If I run something like:

```
  RunTest test = new RunTest(new SetUpUtils().getDriver());
  test.checkLandingPage();
```

the *checkLandingPage* method will run, and fail, but the login and cleanup methods won't run. I've tried a few variations on the annotations, but no luck so far.

The imports used are :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Interaction;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Base64;
```

Comment: can you show the annotation being imported , make sure you are importing from correct class

Comment: I have added it to question , also what is this RunTest? is it a testng method

Comment: @PDHide It's not a testng method, just a class I created to house several methods that run tests.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Not sure how Java is allowing you to have a top level class be static.
2. I would try to run your suite using a TestNG suite.xml file.